# (Unity3d) How to stop character from going to the first position after the animation?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, animator

I am trying to animate a warrior,
He has a special hit using the sword.
Jump, and hit..
During the animation he takes some steps to the front and after the animatiin is done.
It goes back to the idle state leaving the new position.
It annoys too much.
So what I am asking.
How to keep the new position and change the collider position to that new position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to keep the new position

Depends how you animate it. But essentially,

- **Make the animation not loop**
- **Make it not transition to other unwanted animations.**
- **Have the next animation begin from the endpoint of the previous one.**

> and change the collider position to that new position?

**The collider position will follow the position of whichever object it is located on. Also if they are animated**. So if your collider is on a leg and you move the leg outward, the collider will follow that same animation.

---

Additional information

If you don't know how to make things work from here. It would be great to show the code you are using (if any) and how you make the character animate.

If it is with an animation controller, please display the transitions and animations of it in a screenshot.

Always try to provide relevant scripts and screenshots when asking questions.